# linux + .bash_profile + correct PATH syntax

Tags: shell, variable

regarding the file:  **.bash_profile**

what is the different between

```
 PATH=${PATH}:${HOME}/bin:/usr/local/
```

to

```
 PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/usr/local
```

and what is the correct syntax?

Comment: In this case, both are equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing they are both equivalent, when a variable is used in the form:

```
${HOME}
```

the curly braces  serve to delimit the variable WORD when it would otherwise be indistinguishable from another WORD directly adjacent.  e.g.

```
echo $HOMEahoy
```

would produce nothing (except the newline from the `echo`)

```
echo ${HOME}ahoy
```

would echo your home path like you expect plus `ahoy`.
I suspect in this case the `{}` are unnecessary because `=:/` are likely not valid variable characters in `bash` so, bash can work out the WORD boundaries itself.
When shell scripting, if in doubt I always put in the curly braces.
The idea is not limited to `bash` e.g. PHP has similar behaviours - except in PHP they take a slightly different form e.g. `{$VAR_NAME}`